# Reading keys from an .npz file with multiple workers in pytorch dataloader?

Tags: numpy, multiprocessing, pytorch, python-multiprocessing

I have an .npz file where I have stored a dictionary. The dictionary has some keys and the values are numpy arrays. I want to read the dictionary in my **getitem**() method of the dataloader. When I set the dataloader **num_workers** to 1, everything runs fine. But when I increase the num workers, it throws the following error when reading the data from that npz file:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/train.py", line 235, in <module>
    train(args)
  File "scripts/train.py", line 186, in train
    solver(args.epoch, args.verbose)
  File "/local-scratch/codebase/cap/lib/solver.py", line 174, in __call__
    self._feed(self.dataloader["train"], "train", epoch_id)
  File "/local-scratch/codebase/cap/lib/solver.py", line 366, in _feed
    for data_dict in dataloader:
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 819, in __next__
    return self._process_data(data)
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py", line 846, in _process_data
    data.reraise()
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/_utils.py", line 369, in reraise
    raise self.exc_type(msg)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Caught BadZipFile in DataLoader worker process 0.
Original Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/worker.py", line 178, in _worker_loop
    data = fetcher.fetch(index)
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in fetch
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/utils/data/_utils/fetch.py", line 44, in <listcomp>
    data = [self.dataset[idx] for idx in possibly_batched_index]
  File "/local-scratch/codebase/cap/lib/dataset.py", line 947, in __getitem__
    other_bbox_feat = self.box_features['{}-{}_{}.{}'.format(scene_id, target_object_id, ann_id, object_id)]
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 255, in __getitem__
    pickle_kwargs=self.pickle_kwargs)
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 763, in read_array
    data = _read_bytes(fp, read_size, "array data")
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 892, in _read_bytes
    r = fp.read(size - len(data))
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 872, in read
    data = self._read1(n)
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 962, in _read1
    self._update_crc(data)
  File "/local-scratch/anaconda3/envs/scanenv/lib/python3.6/zipfile.py", line 890, in _update_crc
    raise BadZipFile("Bad CRC-32 for file %r" % self.name)
zipfile.BadZipFile: Bad CRC-32 for file 'scene0519_00-13_1.0.npy'
```

As far as I know, pytorch dataloader uses multiprocessing to for data loading. Perhaps the issue is with multiprocessing and .npz files. I really appreciate any help.

Comment: Can the `dataloader` work on these `npz` files without the multiprocessing.  I don't know how `pytorch` treats these files.  They are `zip` archives, where each file is a `npy`.  These are usually loaded with `np.load` which detects the archive nature, and returns a dictionary like object.

Comment: @hpaulj I think there might be an issue with the npz file pointers. Seems like there could be only one pointer reading the npz file at the same time.

Comment: @hpaulj Do you have any suggestions for what file type I should use to store a dictionary of numpy arrays?

Comment: I had this same issue and it only seemed to affect me when running with small data sets. When I increase the data set, the workers are not accessing the npz files at the same time. So I think it's a bug to do with concurrent access to npz files in numpy or zipfile and I've chosen to ignore it and test on larger data!